# razorpay payment gateway not working in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, payment, razorpay

when i go to payment page after entering dummy card detail it shows error

```
{
error: {
code: "BAD_REQUEST_ERROR",
description: "Please do not provide your secret on public sided requests",
source: "NA",
step: "NA",
reason: "NA",
metadata: { }
}
}
```

[image]

I don't know why its give me that error please give some solutions to solve the error

Thank You